# Question on Eigen Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra

Lets say we have a symetric matrix $A=QDQ^T$

Can anyone help me take a look at what is wrong with this argument?

$$A=QDQ^T = DQQ^T =D$$

Note: the first equality is due commutativity of any matrix with diagnal matrices. The second equality is due to QQ' = I.

Comment: $D$ doesn't commute with $Q$. Take $1,2,3$ as the diagonal of $D$.

Comment: @percusse but dont diagnal matrices commute with any matrix?

Comment: No; diagonal matrices commute with _each other_ .

Comment: Diagonals of the form $aI$ commute with arbitrary matrices not all diagonal matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only diagonal matrices which commute with any matrices are those of the form $\lambda I$. For example, consider the matrices:

$A = [[1,0],[2,0]]$ (This matrix scales the $y$ axis by $2$ and the $x$-axis by $1$.)

$B$ the matrix that rotates the plane counter-clockwise by $90$ degrees.

If you follow where the vector $(1,0)$ goes, you will see that these two matrices / linear transformations do not commute with each other.